# Java simple game test errors

Tags: java, game-engine

I am creating simple chess board game in java, and they are running smoothly, however i am getting 2 failures while testing and i don't understand the logic behind them.

**failure #1: player 1 has cloned his king and dominated expected <8> but it was <1>**

**failure #2: Symbols should be treated as an empty cells. expected <1> but it was <0>**

that's my code:

```
import java.io.ObjectInputStream.GetField;

public class ChessBoard {
    public static boolean belongsToPlayer(final char piece, final int player) { // method to check a piece is related to player 1 or 2
        if (player == 0 && Character.isUpperCase(piece)) {
            return true;
        }
        if (player == 1 && Character.isLowerCase(piece)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

     public static int getCount(final String[] board, final int player) { // method to return the number of pieces belonging to each player
         int count = 0;

         if (board.length == 0) {
             return count = 0;
         }
         else if (board.length == 1) {
             return count = 1;
         }
         else {
        int size = board.length;
        for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {        
            for (int j = 0; j < board[i].length(); j++) {

                if (belongsToPlayer(board[i].charAt(j), player)) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
        }
        return count;
    }

}

and these are the test methods:
test #1
@Test(timeout = 1000)
    public void test8KingsPlayer1() {
        String[] board = {
                "kkkkkkkk"
            };
        assertEquals("Player 1 has cloned his king and has dominated", 
                8, instance.getCount(board, PLAYER1));
    }

test #2
@Test(timeout = 1000)
    public void testAPieceOfCode() {
        String[] board = {
                "int factorIal(int n) {",
                "    int n = 8, r = 1; ",
                "    while (n-- > 1)   ",
                "        r *= n;       ",
                "    return r;         ",
                "}                     "
            };
        assertEquals("Symbols should be treated as empty cells.", 
                1, instance.getCount(board, PLAYER0));
    }
```

anyone knows how to solve the problem?

Comment: What are the failures? There's no solution when there isn't a problem...

Comment: for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) will skip the first element in 'board', so try for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) instead

Comment: ok i have edited it and added the explanation of the failures. @Jon

Comment: @PeskyGnat thanks a lot, one failure is solved now :)

Comment: What Pesky said. It seems like this would be trivial to debug if you'd just walk through the code in your head, on paper, or in a debugger.

Comment: the other one fails because your board has one entry, and in that case  else if (board.length == 1) is occuring and you're returning 1.

Comment: yeah, a debugger will help immensely for these types of bugs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Failure 1:

```
else if (board.length == 1) {
    return count = 1;
}
```

It returns 1 right away because you passed it a String[] with 1 element.

Failure 2:

```
for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
    ...
        if (belongsToPlayer(board[i] ...
```

Array indexing starts at 0. You started with 1, which skips the first string in the array. Since the capital I was in the first row, it wasn't counted.